# Using Windows 7 with new Android smartphone

Tags: windows-7, android

Vodafone Smart Ultra 6 comes with no install disks or PC suite like my old phones did.  The PC shows it as an Android device when connected, BUT NO drivers installed or found.

I've asked Vodafone for assistance and maybe some answer will arrive but so far it has told me to go to its online eforum that has no solution for this problem.

So they don't connect - my laptop does not see the phone. I used to use a Samsung, that has Kies and connected directly, before that I had a Sony Ericsson mobile that came with some mind of PC suite disks. Before that Nokia had a great program. Now zilch.

Answer (score 0):

You may still use the google account that is necessary for updates,
or e.g. either dropbox ("share" to it) or google drive in the same style as a file share.

Also if you have other memory than the internal, at least it should 'come up' similar to an USB-flash drive. Maybe depending on settings in the phone

*MTP, PTP, 'Mass storage', other - try switching between them SLOWLY - allow 10-20 seconds, or similar for it to settle*.

*Both internal(Phone) and extra(Card) flash memories are accessible on e.g. Samsung Galaxy S3 and S5; just tried on Ubuntu Linux - you get access to all(?) files - so take care to not break anything.*

What else is there? What more do you expect? *(Samsung KIES was hardly usable for SGS3, especially w.r.t. updates. Nokia and Ericsson "suites" had even less options.)*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your ideas.

Google Drive takes too long to upload, I felt when I tried this. Maybe I didn't do it the best way though. I simply 'shared' the images with Drive.

I haven't tried Dropbox for this purpose.

However, someone, not via this forum, suggested something else that might be painless!

Insert a micro-USB to USB adaptor into the phone. 
Connect a USB memory stick into the USB connector and, as long as it's seen, copy or move files from the phone to the stick. 
To get music on the phone, copy the music files into the memory stick and reverse the process.
I haven't yet given this a go but I shall.
Vodafone Smart Ultra 6 phones have a File Manager built-in, so that ought to make this easier.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please edit your question and include the information from here, then delete this answer.